# How can I get my project to run on the IIS7 server?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, deployment, iis-7, web-config

My ASP.net web application works on my machine, but will not work properly on the test or production server.  It redirects to the login page instead of allowing Anonymous Authentication.  I know that my project properties in Visual Studio include Anonymous Authentication.

Here is my project properties window:

[image]

My web.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
    <!-- Removed for privacy -->
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        <!-- Removed for privacy -->
    </appSettings>
    <location path="ResetPassword.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" requireSSL="false" />
        </authentication>
        <webServices>
            <protocols>
                <add name="HttpGet" />
                <add name="HttpPost" />
            </protocols>
        </webServices>
        <membership>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="<!-- Removed for privacy -->" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="<!-- Removed for privacy -->" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="false">
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="<!-- Removed for privacy -->" applicationName="/" />
                <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
    </system.web>
    <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
            <webServices>
                <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647">
                </jsonSerialization>
            </webServices>
        </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <clear />
                <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I should also mention that this web.config file matches the web.config file that is currently being used in production.  It *should* work, but I just don't understand if there are some additional settings or inherited properties in IIS that are messing things up on my test server.

*Update:  I was able to get this site working on a different server without changing anything in the web.config.  It must be something in the configuration of the server.

Comment: Is Anonymous Authentication enabled in IIS?

Comment: @SBFrancies Yes, I believe Anonymous Authentication is enabled.  If I click on the site and click Authentication, the status of the Anonymous Authentication name is 'Enabled'

Comment: Probably a long shot but there doesn't happen to be an underscore in your machine's name?

Comment: Which pages do you want to be accessed anonymously?

Comment: @SBFrancies Nope there isn't an underscore in the machine's name.  I want the user to be able to reach all pages except for the password reset page and account page.

Comment: On the authentication list of IIS, what else is enabled besides anonymous?

Comment: What is the Windows version including service pack on your test server?

Comment: I doubt that it is Win7, but check [this one](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2526854/users-may-be-redirected-to-the-login-page-of-an-asp-net-4-application).

Comment: @Niko forms authentication is enabled

Comment: Are there external files loaded on the page that could cause the redirects ? Have you debugged via dev tools to see the redirect type ?

Comment: It was Win7.  The bug you mentioned applied.

Comment: Anonymous authentication on IIS and forms authentication in` web.config` clearly indicate that you want to use forms based authentication to restrict access to registered users. So redirecting to the login page is exactly what you should see, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Forms Authentication - When to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665804/asp-net-forms-authentication-when-to-use)